# How to update datagridview with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

i'm new to this multithreading concept and have spent lot of time doing my RnD but not able to get thing done. What I'm trying to do is similar to trading applications . I have A datagridview in windows form showing multiple records in it coming from sql database. it has 4 columns(decimal values).I also have txt files which are updated every minute. I have to read latest line from txt file and compare a decimal values from this line to every decimal column in datagridview. Based on this comparison i'm trying to change color of gridview cells. I find my code logically correct but somehow it's not working.**For every row in grid one thread should start but only one thread is started that is for last record in grid**.I have attached my code .please help me with this.
**InitiateAlert :: It should loop over grid and start a new thread for each record.

### checkiftargetreached :: Each Thread should call this function with parameters. Here the comparison of decimal values is doen and grid cell color is set.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace MultithredingSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnshow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Val1", typeof(decimal)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Val2", typeof(decimal)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Val3", typeof(decimal)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Flag", typeof(Boolean)));

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["id"] = 1;
            dr["Val1"] = 23104.10;
            dr["Val2"] = 23154.10;
            dr["Val3"] = 23845.45;
            dr["Flag"] = true;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["id"] = 2;
            dr["Val1"] = 25104.10;
            dr["Val2"] = 25154.10;
            dr["Val3"] = 25845.45;
            dr["Flag"] = true;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);



            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


        }


private void checkiftargetreached(Int32 rowid,decimal val1,decimal val2, decimal val3, string filepath)
{
string line;
try
   {

   while (Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowid].Cells["Flag"].Value) == 1)
   {

    FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\" + filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    DataTable dtrec = new DataTable();
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    string[] values = line.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i <= values.Length - 1; i++)
    {dtrec.Columns.Add(values[i]);}

  line = sr.ReadLine();
  DataRow dr = dtrec.NewRow();
  string[] values2 = line.Split(',');
  for (int i = 0; i <= values2.Length - 1; i++)
  {dr[i] = values2[i];}
  dtrec.Rows.Add(dr);
  if(Convert.ToDecimal(dtrec.Rows[0][1]) == Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowid].Cells["Val1"].Value))
    {
     if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired){
this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowid].Cells["Val1"].Style.BackColor = Color.Aqua; });
                        }

                    }
  else if (Convert.ToDecimal(dtrec.Rows[0][1]) == Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowid].Cells["Val2"].Value))
                    {
                        if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowid].Cells["Val2"].Style.BackColor = Color.Aqua; this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowid].Cells["Flag"].Value = 0; });
                        }

                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToDecimal(dtrec.Rows[0][1]) == Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowid].Cells["Val3"].Value))
                    {

                        if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowid].Cells["Val3"].Style.BackColor = Color.Aqua; });

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { this.dataGridView1.Rows[rowid].Cells["Val3"].Style.BackColor = Color.IndianRed; });
                        }
                    }



                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void InitiateAlerts()
        {
            Int32 row;
            decimal val1, val2, val3;

            try
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                {

                    if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                        {


                            if (Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Flag"].Value) == 1)
                            {

                                row = j;
                                val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["Val1"].Value);
                                val2 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["Val2"].Value);
                                val3 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["Val3"].Value);

                                Thread TH = new Thread(() => checkiftargetreached(row, val1, val2, val3, "A" + row.ToString() + ".txt"));
                                TH.Name = "A" + row.ToString() + ".csv";
                                TH.Start();
                            }

                        });


                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (Convert.ToInt16(this.dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["Flag"].Value) == 1)
                        {

                            row = j;
                            val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["Val1"].Value);
                            val2 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["Val2"].Value);
                            val3 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells["Val3"].Value);

                            Thread TH = new Thread(() => checkiftargetreached(row, val1, val2, val3, "A" + row.ToString() + ".txt"));
                            TH.Name = "A" + row.ToString() + ".csv";
                            TH.Start();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }

        private void btnthread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitiateAlerts();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if your grid has 300 rows? Will you spawn 300 threads? You should spawn a single thread and use it check files periodically, using a file system watcher. (Assuming that you have to use files for this which is far from optimal.)

Comment: Decimal Values to compare with are available in txt files, generated by some other tool.So i have to reads those files, no other option. I can work on your suggestion of spawning only one thread. But in this scenario i still want to know why only one thread(last in loop) is spawned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial from microsoft.

MS says you need to use "virtualmode"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control#code-snippet-1

Comment: The question has nothing to do with virtual mode.